# Correct word for "unsubmitted"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Looking for a correct word instead of *Unsubmitted* referring to *orders* that have not been submitted yet. *Unsubmitted* seems incorrect since it has not been submitted yet, giving the misleading notion it has been retracted or removed.

I was thinking *Pending* but it sounds like the orders are being held pending a decision but the orders just have not been submitted by the person/user. Is there a more accurate word in the future tense for orders that are to be submitted?

Comment: Maybe you could help us out by elaborating on what state the persons doing the order are in, and how long that process will probably take.

Comment: If the Admin deletes an employees account. And this employee currently has orders sitting that have not been submitted yet. The system prompts the Admin "This user has unsubmitted orders" we do not want to lose those orders by deleting the employee account it's tied to.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use "not submitted" or "as yet unsubmitted?" Does it have to be a single word?

Comment: I just thought there is a word for the future tense of submitted.

Comment: Submitted being past tense... the future tenses of it would include 'submit'

Comment: _Unsubmitted_ sounds the most natural to me, but _pre-submitted_ seems to best describe the state you mean.

Comment: As a native English speaker, I don't see where you get the idea that "unsubmitted" is incorrect. There seems to be something missing from your logic.

Comment: I suggest "staged": planned, organized, or arranged in advance ([Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+staged)).

Answer (score 19):

*Unsubmitted*.

> Unsubmitted seems incorrect since it has not been submitted yet giving the misleading notion it has been retracted or removed.

Those would be retracted, not unsubmitted. The word you want here, is *unsubmitted*.

Comment: I can see, from the point of view of OP, you write an order (and it is in some "saved" state). Then at some point you submit the order and it becomes a "submitted" order (which could be immediately upon writing it, but not necessarily). If submitting that order was an error, or you change your mind, you "unsubmit" the order, and it becomes an "unsubmitted" order. So, if, where OP works, an "unsubmitted" order has the connotation that it is an order that has been submitted, then the submit process has been reversed, then OP needs a different word for an order that has never been submitted.

Comment: @KevinFegan yup, but there's plenty of attested uses of *unsubmitted* to mean not submitted and *retracted* to mean withdrawn after having been submitted.

Comment: I agree. "Unsubmitted" would be my first choice word for not-submitted, or not-yet-submitted. I'm just saying that the OP was already familiar with the word "unsubmitted" and is looking for an alternate (non ambiguous) word/phrase that does not also mean "retracted or removed" to use in a situation where all of those definitions can and likely do apply at various times (for his case). Use of "unsubmitted" in his case would also require additional text to disambiguate the word "unsubmitted". Telling OP they should just use it anyway, while arguably correct,  is not (very) helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Possibilities include:

- Processing
- Under review
- Unsubmitted
- Active
- Aborted
- Uncompleted
- Not placed

Which one makes more sense than another depends on your specific situation. We need to know how a state like this can come to pass.

Edit:
Based on your comment to the addition question I would suggest to use the phrase 'The customer has active orders that are not placed'. Apparently a user was working on an order, but it was not fully completed, and as a result the order could not be placed yet.

Answer (score 1):

**Draft** order or **Drafted** order sounds like it would work for you.

> **draft**
>     /draft/
>     noun: draft; plural noun: drafts;
>     1. a preliminary version of a piece of writing.
>       "the first draft of the party's manifesto"
>
> (Definition by Google)

Comment: This may fit OP's logic, if e finds "unsubmitted" unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

Retract/withdraw would be the opposite to submitted. Those words would not work. I would simply say, "I didn't have time to submit those files." etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Unqueued** orders could work for you, as they are not yet pending. [Queue](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/queue%5B1%5D):

> 2) computers : a series of instructions that are stored in a computer so that they can be processed later
>
> ▪ Three jobs remain in the printer queue.